# VM (Parallels) not using the VPN connection on the host (osx mavericks)

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, parallels

I am running Tunnelblick from my Mac.
My local network is **192.168.0.0/32** and the network I am trying to connect is **192.168.252.0/22**.
Also, I am using a VM (Parallels) running Windows 8.1.
I want to connect to a VPN from my Mac and share this network with my VM.

So, I am facing some problems to do that. Here they go:

- When I'm connected to the VPN, my ip address does not change to the ip address from the VPN network. My ip is still **192.168.0.132**.
- Despite the problem with the ip address, from the host I still can 'ping' the hosts from the network I am trying to connect writing 'ping host.domain.com'. But 'ping host' does not work.
- I've already set the network to ‘shared’ in the device menu from Parallels. But, even with this, my ip address from the VM is **10.211.55.4**.
- In my VM I can't even ping the hosts from the other network

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough. All this problem is a little complex to describe.
Something important: The same configuration file I am using works perfectly (without the IP and the DNS problems) when I am using a Windows machine.

Answer (score 2):

Change the VM's network adapter type to "Shared" within Parallels Desktop.

Comment: As I said, I've already set the network to ‘shared’ and it doesn't work.

Comment: Missed that, sorry. It will be helpful to see how network config works when VPN is connected. Send from mac Host (ifconfig, netstat -rn) and Windows (ipconfig /all, route print)

Answer (score 1):

1. Configure virtual machine
2. Change network source to shared network
3. if that still does not work, disable ipv6 in guest machine.